# SignalR connections with IIS windows authentication stops working with more than 6 connections

Tags: signalr

Trying to connect to website from multiple windows and expecting the data refresh to happen 
in all windows.

Hub connection with SignalR 2.0 version

MVC4 website

IIS 8.0 on windows 2012 server.

Chrome browser

When anonymous authentication is enabled, the multiple browser connections from same user to SignalR works fine. The moment anonymous authentication is disabled and windows authentication is enabled, the signalR limits only few connections from same browser and the data refresh  stops working.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on the amount  can open concurrent connections for a browser

from here : 
Max Number of default simultaneous persistent connections per server/proxy:

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```

Comment: It works fine with anonymous authentication. Why doesn't it work with windows authentication?

Comment: If you're testing in chrome, w/o windows auth you'll be using web sockets which doesn't count as a concurrent connection.. when you turn on windows auth you're not using web sockets any more (it's a really dumb chrome bug)